# Temperature Plot: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'y' not found

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, viridis

I am trying to **plot the temperatures** while taking the code from the link below:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggjoy/vignettes/gallery.html

[image]

Here the author used y-axis as month axis but I want to use x-axis as month axis and y-axis as temperature axis.

The data can be downloaded from the foloowing link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByOfjCmqEilLYndpOWJyZXhPVUk/view

The code is given below:

```
enter code here
library(ggjoy)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(viridis)

setwd <- 'C:/Users/Data/'
weather.raw <- read.csv(file="nebraska-2016.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
weather.raw$month<-months(as.Date(weather.raw$Date))
weather.raw$months<-
        factor(rev(weather.raw$month),levels=rev(unique(weather.raw$month)))

mins<-min(weather.raw$Min.TemperatureF)
maxs<-max(weather.raw$Max.TemperatureF)

ggplot(weather.raw, aes(x = months , y = Mean.TemperatureF, fill = ..y..)) + 
geom_joy_gradient(scale = 1, rel_min_height = 0.01, gradient_lwd = 1.) +
scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
scale_fill_viridis(name = "Temp. [°C]", option = "C") +
labs(title = 'Temperatures',
subtitle = 'Histogram of Mean Temperatures (°F) - 2016') +
theme_joy(font_size = 13, grid = TRUE) + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

It gives the following error.

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'y' not found

Comment: Please provide the command you use to read the data from the url.

Comment: You can directly download the data as .csv file from the link.

Comment: I have also update the code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggjoy)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(viridis)

weather.raw <- read.csv(file="nebraska-2016.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
weather.raw$month <- months(as.Date(weather.raw$CST))
weather.raw$months <- factor(weather.raw$month,levels=unique(weather.raw$month))

weather.raw$Mean.TemperatureF <- (weather.raw$Mean.TemperatureF-32)/1.8

ggplot(weather.raw, aes(x = Mean.TemperatureF, y = months , fill = ..x..)) + 
geom_joy_gradient(aes(x=Mean.TemperatureF), scale = 1, 
                  rel_min_height = 0.01, gradient_lwd = 1.) + 
coord_flip() +
scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
scale_fill_viridis(name = "Temp. [°C]", option = "C") +
labs(title = 'Temperatures',
subtitle = 'Histogram of Mean Temperatures (°C) - 2016') +
theme_joy(font_size = 13, grid = TRUE) + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]